# can't open -sectcreate file in Xcode NativeScript

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to extend my existing iOS app with **Angular 2** and **NativeScript**. It was working fine after all the change have been done with this tutorial ([Extend your existing iOS app with Angular 2 and NativeScript](https://medium.com/@enchev/extend-your-existing-ios-app-with-angular-2-and-nativescript-c2225c9bf616#.41vvrpva4)). Later when I'm changing **app** files, then I'm getting these errors with **Linker Flags** to build:

> ld: can't open -sectcreate file: “/Users/MacPro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeScriptCustom-azbyrrgduygzuvbxpxodgarpvtgy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-x86_64.bin”
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I'm removing those Linker Flags to build, then there is no errors. But, when I'm running the app, it's stopping with this breakpoint:

> Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)

This is the code which is come to breakpoint without linker flags

```
// Tell NativeScript where to look for the app folder. Its existence is optional, though.
_runtime = [[TNSRuntime alloc] initWithApplicationPath:path];
```

help me out from this issue and I'm new in this **NativeScript** cross-platform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Added **Run Script**

> cd "$PROJECT_DIR/internal/metadata-generator/bin" && ./metadata-generation-build-step

into following one

> "$SRCROOT/internal/nativescript-pre-build"

then drag the keep the **Run Script** second one (After **Target Dependencies**). Like following :

[image: After Target Dependencies added Run Script]

**NOTE:** make sure that Run script only when installing unchecked. Keep all the **Linker Flags** to build and use the metadata. 
The Linker Flags :

> -sectcreate __DATA __TNSMetadata "$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/metadata-$(CURRENT_ARCH).bin"